Getting uniform coordinates from a 3D plane projected as a 2D plane
3d plane projected to a 2d polygon
I have the coordinates of the vertexes P1, P2, P3 and P4 that define a rectangular rectangle.
Those coordinates always define a regular rectangular area and the distortion of the plane defined by those coordinates, in the image above, is only due to perspective.
I have those coordinates (P1, P2, P3 and P4) in world-space.
I also have the coordinates of a point C, in world-space, that is not in the plane defined by P1, P2, P3 and P4 but is somewhere between the camera location and the plane defined by P1, P2, P3 and P4.
I already have a way to calculate if, seen from the camera, C is inside the boundary defined by P1, P2, P3 and P4, by converting all the coordinates from world to screen-space and checking if the screen-space point C is inside the screen-space triangle P1 - P2 - P3 or triangle P1 - P3 - P4.
So, if P1, P2, P3 and P4 always define a regular rectangle and if C in inside the area defined by P1, P2, P3 and P4 as they are seen from the camera, how can I calculate the uniform coordinates from 0,0 (at P2, for example) to 1,1 (at P4, for example) of the point C, if it was projected to the plane defined by P1, P2, P3 and P4?
I mean, in the example image, I expect to get a result of around 0.8, 0.45 for the uniform coordinates correspondent to the location of point C.
If the point C screen projection was correspondent to the screen location of point P2, I should get 0,0
If the point C screen projection was correspondent to the screen location of point P1, I should get 1,0
If the point C screen projection was correspondent to the screen location of point P3, I should get 0,1
If the point C screen projection was correspondent to the screen location of point P4, I should get 1,1
Basically, I need to calculate the uniform coordinates from 0,0 to 1,1 inside a single regular plane (that can be distorted in the view due to perspective), of the projection of a point that is between the camera and that plane, onto that plane. However I just have the vertex coordinates and the point coordinates (in 3d world space and in 2d screen space).
I hope I explained it all clearly enough.
Can anyone help? Thank you so much.
Oh, I'm using python but I don't mind if the solution is in any other language or even pseudo-code.

I managed to solve this by calculating the barycentric coordinates of the two triangles that form the quadrilateral shape.
So, I can check if the point is inside the rectangle and also derive the uv coordinates from the calculated u,v and w components of the barycentric coordinates.
def get_uvs(pw1,pw2,pw3,pw4):
    # quadrilateral is defined by pw1,pw2,pw3 and pw4 2d vectors, in screen-space

    vv = 1.0/(2*area(pw1,pw2,pw3)) * (pw1.y*pw3.x - pw1.x*pw3.y + (pw3.y-pw1.y) * p_uv.x + (pw1.x-pw3.x)*p_uv.y)
    ww = 1.0/(2*area(pw1,pw2,pw3)) * (pw1.x*pw2.y - pw1.y*pw2.x + (pw1.y-pw2.y) * p_uv.x + (pw2.x-pw1.x)*p_uv.y)
    uu = 1.0 - vv - ww  
    if uu>0 and vv>0 and ww>0: return uu,ww

    vv = 1.0/(2*area(pw3,pw4,pw1)) * (pw3.y*pw1.x - pw3.x*pw1.y + (pw1.y-pw3.y) * p_uv.x + (pw3.x-pw1.x)*p_uv.y)
    ww = 1.0/(2*area(pw3,pw4,pw1)) * (pw3.x*pw4.y - pw3.y*pw4.x + (pw3.y-pw4.y) * p_uv.x + (pw4.x-pw3.x)*p_uv.y)
    uu = 1.0 - vv - ww
    if uu>0 and vv>0 and ww>0: return = 1.0-uu,1.0-ww

    return -1,-1 # return negative results if not inside quadrilateral
    
#---------------------------------------------------------

def area(p0, p1, p2):
    return 0.5*(-p1.y*p2.x + p0.y*(-p1.x+p2.x) + p0.x*(p1.y-p2.y)+ p1.x*p2.y)

